# How to reference taxonomy used by other content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have two content types: **Content A** and **Content B**

Fields in **Content A**: Title, Location, Body

Fields in **Content B**: Title, Type, Location, Body

**Location** is a vocabulary (Au, Uk, Us, Ca, etc)

Type is an *entity reference* of Content A inside Content B node.

Content A has a node with information in order:
*News X, Ca, This is the body of News X*

Content B has a node with information in order:
*John Doe, Content A, ????, This is about John Doe*

In this question mark, I want to include **Location** but only that which is selected in that node of **Content A**.

Location can be multiple, that is, if Content A node has "location": Ca, Uk
then Content B node referenced to Content A will only enlist Ca, Uk out of all other terms in that vocabulary.

---

I have looked into google, found nothing. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

## For simple displaying of taxonomy term

Assuming your are using [entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) for Drupal 7 the module provides out of the box a field formatter that allows you to display the **Rendered entity** with a specific **view mode**

Thus you can display the referenced entity with the taxonomy term included.

Go to the **manage display** of your **Content B** and change the format to *Rendered entity* and choose *teaser* for the *view mode*

[image]

Go to the **manage display** of your **Content A** and modify the **teaser** view mode and add the taxonomy term field to be displayed.

## For more advanced use cases

You might want to try any combination of the following

- [field_extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_extractor) to extract a specific field from a referenced entity
- [inline_entity_display](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_display) similar to above
- [field_reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_reference) refer to specific field on the same node/entity or other node/entities